# why does my nodejs function returning undefined?

Tags: node.js, express

```
function getUserByStudentId(NIM) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM data_admin WHERE id_mahasiswa = ?', [NIM], async (err, result) => {
        if (!result) {
            return null
        } else {
            var data = await {
                id: result[0].id_Admin,
                email: result[0].email,
                jabatan: result[0].jabatan,
                password: result[0].password,
                id_mahasiswa: result[0].id_mahasiswa,
                id_Acara: result[0].id_Acara,
                id_Organisasi: result[0].id_Organisasi
            }
            console.log(data) // there is a value here
            return data
        }
    })
}

console.log(getUserByStudentId('1301194051')) // undefined returned
```

I'm a student and start learning nodejs. Would you explain to me, why my function returning undefined

```
console.log(getUserByStudentId('1301194051')) // undefined
```

but when I console.log on the function I got returned value

Comment: How are you returning data and showing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll promisify the function for you:

```js
function getUserByStudentId(NIM) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM data_admin WHERE id_mahasiswa = ?', [NIM], (err, result) => {
            if (!result) {
                resolve(null);
            } else {
                var data = {
                    id: result[0].id_Admin,
                    email: result[0].email,
                    jabatan: result[0].jabatan,
                    password: result[0].password,
                    id_mahasiswa: result[0].id_mahasiswa,
                    id_Acara: result[0].id_Acara,
                    id_Organisasi: result[0].id_Organisasi
                }
                console.log(data) // there is a value here
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If you're going to use this function in global scope, use `then`:

```js
getUserByStudentId('1301194051').then(result => {
   console.log(result);
});
```

If you want to use this function inside an async function, you can await the result:

```js
async function doSomethingWithUser(NIM) {
    const user = await getUserByStudentId(NIM);
}
```

For example, if you're using express:

```js
app.get('/user/:id', async (res, req) => {
   const NIM = req.param.id;
   const user = await getUserByStudentId(NIM);
   res.json({ user });
});
```

Comment: ```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) => {
```
well, if you want to use arrow function, you doesn't need reguler 'function' syntax anymore, but thx your code it's work, thx